# How to execute methods in base class when mixing in modules?

Tags: ruby, rails-activejob

I am trying to execute a method in a base class from an included module. So let's say I have the following code

```
module B
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    # code to execute A.new.my_instance_method
    # code to execute A.my_static_method
  end

  def my_module_instance_method
    puts 'module_instance_method'
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def my_module_static_method
      puts 'module_static_method'
    end
  end
end

class A
  include B

  def my_instance_method
    puts 'Instance Method'
  end

  def self.my_static_method
    puts 'static method'
  end
end
```

How would I get the two methods to execute?

Essentially I am trying to extend ActiveJob and I want to override around_perform. I want to achieve this by mixing in a module that adds around_perform to the job and fires some code before and after my job. I have been trying to understand how modules work, but there are still gaps in understanding how things work. From what I have read, this is similar to what I need.

Any direction appreciated.

Comment: `self.included` callback is called when ruby executes _class declaration_ of `A`, exactly in place where `include B` appeared. **TL;DR**: put `include B` in the very end of `A` declaration.

Comment: @mudasobwa: it's not that TL :)

Comment: Thanks, that works. However it's more common to include a module at the top of a file. Since this approach would make using this library a little more complicated and confusing, is there not  a way to do this where I can include the module at the top? I am guessing not.

Comment: I just copy&pasted your code and didn't get any errors or anything suspicious. Either there is no problem or your code is not representative of your problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am not sure if you have read the whole question or code, but the code does not have an error per se. Look at the commented out code to see what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two other options to your issue. The `around_perform` is an `ActiveJob::Base` class method which stores the block or method to be called around perform. So you need to call this method at class level. The 2 options are:

1. Subclassing: Have a base `ActiveJob::Base` subclass (ex: `MainJob)` which has the `around_perform` thing and all your jobs should subclass `MainJob` instead of `ActiveJob::Base`
2. Set the `around_perform` callback in the included block:

In the exmple below I'm using `ActiveSupport::Concern`

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module TheModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    around_perform do |job, block|
      puts "#{job.class.name} Look I'm being called"
      block.call
      puts "#{job.class.name} Look I was called"
    end
  end
end
```

And `include TheModule` in your job classes

PS: I would go for the #1 (inheritance) as it seems more 'natural' to me